# Interpret php post from url into variables

Tags: php, url, post

Im am very new to PHP (although i am programmed in object-c programming for iOS and this is why i need this).
I need to get the username and password out of a post url and into variables for example this:
http://url.com/phpFile.php?username=TheUsernameToGetOut&password=ThePasswordToGetOut
Many Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a POST or a GET request? PHP handles those differently. Your link suggest you mean a GET request, but you're saying POST... so it's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the parameters sent in the url (**Get parameters**) through the super global array `$_GET`. example:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

[$_GET from php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

If the parameters were sent instead via a post (**posting a form**) then they will be available through the `$_POST` super global array. example:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

[$_POST from php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a query string to pass such a sensitive information like username and password.

So, there should be just http://example.com/phpFile.php accessed with POST method and thus you will get your variables vis

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

All the GET parameters will be stored in $_GET global array and all POST parameters will be stored in $_POST

```
$username = $_POST['username']
$password = $_POST['password']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the username and password from url. So why are you using $_POST
It will not work. Use $_GET or $_REQUEST

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```